# Цвет текста не отображается

Tags: python, текст

'''

```
import random
import sys
print("Приветствую тебя, дорогой игрок!")
print("Ты попал в казино!")
print("скажи спасибо что не на деньги(пока что)")
money = int(input("Сколько денег выделите для игры? "))
while money > 0:
    a = random.randint(1, 9)
    b = random.randint(1, 9)
    c = random.randint(1, 9)
    if a==7 and b==7 and c==7:
        money+=1000
        def out_blue(text):
            print("\033[35m {}" .format(text))
        out_blue("ДЖЕКПОТ!!!")
        #print ("ДЖЕКПОТ!!!")
        sys.exit
    elif a==7 and b==7:
        money+=100
        def out_yellow(text):
            print("\033[33m {}" .format(text))
        out_yellow("Поздравляю, вы выиграли 100 грн, ваш счёт: ")
        print(money)
        #print ("Поздравляю, вы выиграли 100 грн, ваш счёт: ", money)
    elif a==7 or b==7 and c==7:
        money+=10
        def out_red(text):
            print("\033[31m {}" .format(text))
        out_red("Поздравляю, вы выиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт: ")
        print(money)
        #print ("Поздравляю, вы выиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт: ", money)
    else:
        money-=10
        print ("Вы проиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт: ", money)
print("Вы проиграли все деньги, попробуйте ещё раз, в следующий раз обязательно получится!")
```

'''

Написала такой код, но выводится весь текст синим, абсолютно ничего не меняется

> Вы проиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт:  500
> [31m Поздравляю, вы выиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт:
> 510
> [31m Поздравляю, вы выиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт:
> 520
> Вы проиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт:  510
> [31m Поздравляю, вы выиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт:
> 520
> Вы проиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт:  510
> Вы проиграли 10 грн, ваш счёт:  500

Answer (score 1):

ANSI коды работают на большинстве дистрибутивов Linux, но не поддерживаются консолью операционной системы Windows до Windows 10. [Статья для справки.](https://all-python.ru/osnovy/tsvetnoj-vyvod-teksta.html)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы активировать цвета в Windows можно использовать модуль `colorama`.

Устанавливаем модуль:

```
pip install colorama
```

Импортируем его и вызываем функцию `init()`:

```
from colorama import init
init()
```

После этого цвета должны заработать.